# geopandas geometry.within problem ValueError: Geometry column cannot contain mutiple geometry types

Tags: python, overlay, geopandas, within

I'm trying to do an overlap of some lines with polygons with geopandas. 
[image]

For a reason I don't understand, `gpd.overlay(grid, hel, how='intersection')` is not made for lines and polygons, so I'm trying to do it like this:

`final = grid[grid.geometry.within(hel)]
  final.to_file('output.shp')`

but I get this error: `ValueError: Geometry column cannot contain mutiple geometry types when writing to file.` I don't see how this processing can give any different geometry type rather than line.

If I the overlay in QGIS it works perfectly.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
As pointed in the comments, this error comes from `to_file` command, caused by trying to write an empty GDF. This error can be reproduced by :

```
g = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
g['geometry'] = None
g.to_file('testburro.shp')
```

I will open an issue about this, the error message is totally misleading.

Back to my problem, this code produces the desired output:

```
with fiona.open(filename1, 'r') as layer1:
with fiona.open(file_name, 'r') as layer2:
    index = rtree.index.Index()
    for feat1 in layer1:
        fid = int(feat1['id'])
        if feat1['geometry']:
            geom1 = shape(feat1['geometry'])
            index.insert(fid, geom1.bounds)
    drv = layer1.driver
    crs = layer1.crs
    schema = {"geometry": "LineString", "properties": {"id": "int"}}
    output_name = 'output.shp'
    with fiona.open(output_name, 'w', driver=drv, schema=schema, crs=crs) as dst_layer:
        for feat2 in layer2:
            geom2 = shape(feat2['geometry'])
            for fid in list(index.intersection(geom2.bounds)):
                feat1 = layer1[fid]
                geom1 = shape(feat1['geometry'])
                if geom1.intersects(geom2):
                    geom3 = geom1.intersection(geom2)
                    dst_layer.write({'geometry': mapping(geom3), "properties": {"id": feat1}})
                    print('{} intersects {}'.format(feat2['id'], feat1['id']))
```

So I don't think is a problem of the dataset.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Also, the error you give, is only possible to get if you did a `to_file` call, not with the `grid[grid.geometry.within(hel)]` operation I think. But in the code snippets you give, there is nothing about writing to a file.

Comment: Indeed there is a `to_file`, but I think the problem is another: When I do `grid[grid.geometry.within(hel)]` `grid[grid.geometry.intersects(hel)]`it returns an empty GDF, when obviously they intersect, and also, doing it thought spatial index it works. See edit.

Comment: About `overlay` not working with lines, that's indeed currently a limitation of the function. For `grid[grid.geometry.within(hel)]`, I think you are bitten by the fact that if you do a `within` operation between two GeoSeries, then they are first aligned on the index and then do an element-wise within (so s1[0].within(s2[0]), s1[1].within(s2[1]), etc...). This might not be what you want.